# How to get tweets from my home page

Tags: php, twitter

I am new in twitter Api ... but i read some in the documentations.

Now in my twitter account i have followers and they tweets displayed in my home page.

I want using PHP get all tweets that displayed in my home page ... all what i can do so far to get my tweets only.

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";

// Make Requests
$header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
              CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
              CURLOPT_URL => $url , 
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

$twitter_data = json_decode($json);
```

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `home_timeline.json` instead of `user_timeline.json";`

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json";

// Make Requests
$header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
              CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
              CURLOPT_URL => $url , 
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

$twitter_data = json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Twitter widget for doing like this..

sample code

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/@username"  data-widget-id="438248826176933888">Tweets by @username</a>
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

replace @username with your twitter name

Comment: i want it with php not just a script